# Sympy returns Integrate when integrating with a constant sometimes

Tags: sympy

I am trying to integrate a seemingly simple equation but can't.
This is the equation:

```
sin(x)
------
x + n·pi
```

So when I do

```
import sympy as sym
x = sym.Symbol("x")
n = sym.Symbol("n", real = True, constant = True)
sym.integrate(sym.sin(x)/(x+sym.pi*n),x)
```

I get `Integral(sin(x)/(pi*n + x), x)`. I have tried other solutions like `.doit()` and `.evalf()` but to no avail.

- If I declare `n = 3` or other random number then it works.
- It also works if n is outside as in `sym.integrate(sym.sin(x)/(x+sym.pi)/n, x)`. This is obviuosly not the same formula but still
- When inputting the formula into wolframalpha it gets computed instantly.

How to make sympy calculate this?

Answer (score 1):

Sympy's integration algorithms appear to be very sensitive to assumptions. For example, assuming `n` to be a positive integer, then SymPy is able to compute the result:

```
import sympy as sym
x = sym.Symbol("x")
n = sym.Symbol("n", integer=True, positive=True)
res = sym.integrate(sym.sin(x)/(x+sym.pi*n),x)
res
# out: exp(I*pi*n)*Si(pi*n + x)
```

You can then simplify it:

```
res.simplify()
# out: (-1)**n*Si(pi*n + x)
```

Comment: I don't think the result is valid for noninteger n.